# Change line spacing in code listings environnement

Tags: listings, line-spacing

I can't get a small line spacing for the code environment.
How to force it? `basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}` doesn't change anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\linespread{1.5}

\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{10pt}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttm\linespread{0.8},
}

\begin{document}
The line spacing is perfect here.

The line spacing is perfect here too.

\begin{lstlisting}
The code has 
too high 
line spacing
\end{lstlisting}

The line spacing is perfect here.

The line spacing is perfect here too.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the command `\selectfont` to "activate" the line spacing changes:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttm\linespread{0.8}\selectfont
}
```

> [image]

If you dislike the extra spacing below the listing, you can also set `belowskip=0pt`.

Comment: This is correct. I've been wandering around many posts suggesting the use of `\linespread` but none of those mentioned `\selectfont`. Thanks.